# flutter drawer to remember the clicked item

Tags: flutter

I want to remember the item that was clicked in drawer .

I am using the same widget for drawer ( sameDrawerOnly ) in all three widgets ( MyHomePage , FirstPage and SecondPage) and using variable itemClicked to trackthe item that was tapped inside setState . But the conditional formatting is not working.

Here is the code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

DrawerOnly sameDrawerOnly = DrawerOnly();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final appTitle = 'Drawer Demo';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: MyHomePage(title: appTitle),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(title)),
      body: Center(child: Text('My Page!')),
      drawer: sameDrawerOnly,
    );
  }
}

class DrawerOnly  extends StatefulWidget {
  const DrawerOnly ({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DrawerOnlyState createState() => _DrawerOnlyState();
}

class _DrawerOnlyState extends State<DrawerOnly > {

  int itemClicked = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctxt) {
    return Drawer(
        child: new ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            new DrawerHeader(
              child: new Text("DRAWER HEADER.."),
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.orange
              ),
            ),
            new ListTile(
              title: new Text("Item => A", style: itemClicked==1 ? TextStyle(  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.6) ) : null),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pop(ctxt);

                setState(() {
                  itemClicked=1;
                });
                Navigator.push(ctxt,
                    new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctxt) => new FirstPage()));
              },
            ),
            new ListTile(
              title: new Text("Item => 2", style: itemClicked==2 ? TextStyle(  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold , color: Colors.green.withOpacity(0.6) ) : TextStyle()),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pop(ctxt);

                setState(() {
                  itemClicked=2;
                });
                Navigator.push(ctxt,
                    new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctxt) => new SecondPage()));
              },
            ),
          ],
        )
    );
  }
}

class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctxt) {
    return new Scaffold(
      drawer: sameDrawerOnly,
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("First Page"),),
      body: new Text("I belongs to First Page"),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctxt) {
    return new Scaffold(
      drawer: sameDrawerOnly,
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Second Page"),),
      body: new Text("I belongs to Second Page"),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**What went wrong**

Although `sameDrawerOnly` was declared at the top most part of your file. Everytime the widget re-draws your app's screens, eg. opening `FirstPage` via `MaterialPageRoute`, the variable in the `DrawerOnly` widget will always stay to zero. Because it is always re-drawn based on your configuration.

**What you can do**

Hotfix: Make `itemClicked` a static variable. (Not Recommended)

```
// Before
int itemClicked

// After
static int itemClicked
```

Alternatively, you can refactor your code and use `PageView` instead of opening a new `Scaffold` widget every time you switch between drawer items. Then, you can now use `currentPageValue` to determine what item was selected by the user.

**MyHomePage.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final appTitle = 'Drawer Demo';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: MyHomePage(title: appTitle),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  createState() => MyHomePageState();
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  PageController _pageController;
  double currentPageValue = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pageController = PageController();
    _pageController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        currentPageValue = _pageController.page;
        // Do whatever you like with the page value
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.title)),
      body: Center(
        child: PageView(
          controller: _pageController,
          children: <Widget>[
            FirstPage(),
            SecondPage(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        // Add a ListView to the drawer. This ensures the user can scroll
        // through the options in the drawer if there isn't enough vertical
        // space to fit everything.
        child: ListView(
          // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[
            DrawerHeader(
              child: Text('Drawer Header'),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Item 1'),
              onTap: () {
                _pageController.jumpToPage(0);
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Item 2'),
              onTap: () {
                _pageController.jumpToPage(1);
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(color: Colors.red);
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(color: Colors.yellow);
  }
}
```

*View on [dartpad.dev](http://dartpad.dev/a05f25071035213b59046e30537fa220).*

More on:

- https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/drawer

Comment: Doesn't work on the Dartpad link you shared. Container color does not update on ListTile `onTap`.

Comment: Thank you for waiting for me. I have updated the API from `jumpTo` to `jumpToPage`. It should work fine now. Hope it helps.

Comment: @joshua-de-guzman I liked your code, how can I land on SecondPage when application starts while still keeing it as second Item in PageView ?

Comment: If you're talking about opening the app after quitting the app, the only option you have to meet your requirement, or at least your use case, is by saving the state using [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) plugin. It's a simple way of saving and retrieving a non-critical data.

Comment: Hi @puzzled, let me know if this helps. Your follow up question is a bit a separate concern from your original question, given the scenario. The "marked as answer" was removed as well. Sad.